# Visual Studio 2015 Team Explorer error write access denied comes and goes

Tags: visual-studio, github, visual-studio-2015, tfs, team-explorer

I have a school group project on TFS and working with VS 2015. I can connect to Team Explorer and sync up with the solution just fine. However when I start working on my local version I get the 'Save As' pop up box when I attempt to save code I'm working on just recently. That save as pop up shouldn't happen. I can also see the file inside the pop up, but I'll attempt to go ahead and save it, but when I do I get this error message, "The process cannot access the file '' because it is being used by another process" or I will see this error message 'An error occurred. Detailed message:  for writing: Access is denied."

I also get the Access is denied error on Team Explorer when I attempt to undo changes on that particular file.

The crazy thing is that this isn't a consistent issue, after a minute or so I can save the file just fine and move on.

Any help would be appreciated on this annoyance?

Note: I have tried going into the file explorer path of the file and remove it (and allow team explorer to pull it back down from server) but once i get into that last folder, File Explorer closes...

Comment: Hi Nick, do you happen to have an anti-virus program scanning that directory holding your source?  I have seen in the past where anti-virus scanning can interfere with Visual Studio being able to save the file.

Comment: Not that I'm aware of. Windows did an automatic update last week and that's when I notice the VS odd things happening.

Comment: Please try to clean the TFS cache at your local machine, the path is `C:\Users\***\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\6.0\Cache`. And create a new workspace, does that folder still can't be saved?

Comment: Could you please let other users to checkout that file and try to save it, does other person could save it?

Comment: I've tested the checkout file check. That wasn't the issue. So far in the last few days I haven't noticed any issue but if a hiccup occurs I will clear the cache in AppData and see what happens. Thank you for your input.

Comment: Ok, I am able to commit and do a pull request on my branch just fine. However when I try to sync back up with master (after deleting my local branch) I get that access is denied error on a file I worked on. So i did the remove cache and created a new workspace. Let's see how this plays out. Thanks again.

Comment: You are using Git or TFVC in TFS? I though you're using TFVC, but from the newest comment, you're using Git.

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout the deleted local branch first and try to sync again in your local git repository. 
[image]